# Error 2 'WebDataGrid' is ambiguous in the namespace 'Infragistics.Web.UI.GridControls'

Tags: asp.net, infragistics

I have a regular aspx web page and one time I tried to debug it, it randomly gives me this issue:

Error   2   'WebDataGrid' is ambiguous in the namespace 'Infragistics.Web.UI.GridControls'.

this is part of my code

```
<%@ Register Assembly="Infragistics45.Web.v13.1, Version=13.1.20131.2331, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7dd5c3163f2cd0cb"
    Namespace="Infragistics.Web.UI.GridControls" TagPrefix="ig" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">

    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <ig:WebDataGrid ID="WebDataGrid1" runat="server" Height="350px" Width="400px">
            </ig:WebDataGrid>
        </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

this is my web.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="infragistics.web" type="System.Configuration.SingleTagSectionHandler,System, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
    <sectionGroup name="businessObjects">
      <sectionGroup name="crystalReports">
        <section name="rptBuildProvider" type="CrystalDecisions.Shared.RptBuildProviderHandler, CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, Custom=null"/>
      </sectionGroup>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="masterConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=dmandelbaum_pc\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <infragistics.web styleSetName="Default" styleSetPath="~/ig_res"/>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="Infragistics4.Web.v13.1, Version=13.1.20131.2331, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7DD5C3163F2CD0CB"/>
        <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="Infragistics4.WebUI.Documents.Reports.v13.1, Version=13.1.20131.2331, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7DD5C3163F2CD0CB"/>
        <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
        <add assembly="Infragistics4.WebUI.Documents.Excel.v13.1, Version=13.1.20131.2331, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7DD5C3163F2CD0CB"/>
        <add assembly="Infragistics4.WebUI.Documents.Word.v13.1, Version=13.1.20131.2331, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7DD5C3163F2CD0CB"/>
        <add assembly="Infragistics4.WebUI.Documents.IO.v13.1, Version=13.1.20131.2331, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7DD5C3163F2CD0CB"/>
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportSource, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
        <add assembly="Infragistics45.Web.v13.1, Version=13.1.20131.2331, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7DD5C3163F2CD0CB"/>
        <add assembly="Infragistics45.WebUI.Documents.Reports.v13.1, Version=13.1.20131.2331, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7DD5C3163F2CD0CB"/>
        <add assembly="Infragistics45.WebUI.Documents.Excel.v13.1, Version=13.1.20131.2331, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7DD5C3163F2CD0CB"/>
        <add assembly="Infragistics45.WebUI.Documents.Word.v13.1, Version=13.1.20131.2331, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7DD5C3163F2CD0CB"/>
        <add assembly="Infragistics45.WebUI.Documents.IO.v13.1, Version=13.1.20131.2331, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7DD5C3163F2CD0CB"/>
      </assemblies>
      <buildProviders>
        <add extension=".rpt" type="CrystalDecisions.Web.Compilation.RptBuildProvider, CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
      </buildProviders>
    </compilation>
  </system.web>
  <businessObjects>
    <crystalReports>
      <rptBuildProvider>
        <add embedRptInResource="true"/>
      </rptBuildProvider>
    </crystalReports>
  </businessObjects>
</configuration>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try to restart VS project. Can you provide your web.config file here?

Comment: Try explicit reference to (Infragistics45.Web.v13.1) dll in your server side code.

Answer (score 0):

The error that you are getting indicates that there are two versions of the Infragistics.Web assembly loaded and since the type exists in both the compiler doesn't know which one to use.

If you look closely at the web.config you will see both references:

```
<add assembly="Infragistics4.Web.v13.1, Version=13.1.20131.2331, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7DD5C3163F2CD0CB"/>
<add assembly="Infragistics45.Web.v13.1, Version=13.1.20131.2331, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7DD5C3163F2CD0CB"/>
```

To resolve the specific error the Infragistics4.Web.v13.1 reference should be removed.

Note that there are also duplicate references in the web.config for other Infragistics assemblies that should also be removed.  If these are not removed you may see similar errors for other classes.

Also it wouldn't matter if you remove the 4 or 45 versions of the assemblies and I suggested removing the 4 version because the Register tag in your page (or user control) references the 45 version.